# Can we permission to user account for modify any file in any drive?

Tags: windows, user-accounts, home-directory

We have a PC that has one account, the Administrator. I created a user account with member of user permission. Problem is that I can not modify, type and save any `.xls`, `.doc` or `.ppt` file.

So, are there any settings available which helps me save those files in User account?

Comment: Would depend on where you were saving your file, so try to save it on `My Documents` that, for the current user, should have the right permissions set.

Answer (score 0):

You said that you have gave the user account permissions to the folder that you want then to have access to. I would give the user the full control permission for the folder that you want them to have access to. You can also to add that user account to the administrator group. Then reboot, and you should be able to modify the files that you want.